# Getting $injector:modulerr after including ['ngRoute']

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Having a `$injector:modulerr` error after including ngRoute. Using AngularJS 1.2.26

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {controller: indexController1, templateURL: 'index1.html'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view/:id', {controller: indexController2, templateURL: 'index2.html'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
app.controller('indexController1', function ($scope) { .... }
app.controller('indexController2', function ($scope, $routeParams) { .... }
```

---

html template

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the error. Don't use minified files during development. And think about this: have you defined variables named indexController1 and indexController2? Then how can you use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

**The .config**

You should use nested `.when` instead of again define `$routeProvider`

Name of the controllers between quotes

Missing closing `);` in controllers

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'index1.html',
         controller: 'indexController1'
     })
     .when('/view/:id', {
         templateUrl: 'index2.html',
         controller: 'indexController2'
     })
     .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
     });
});

app.controller('indexController1', function ($scope) {

});

app.controller('indexController2', function ($scope, $routeParams) {

});
```

**The html**

Missing `</script>` close tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Check here a working example [ngRoute](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wf7POLXpqbrmyiRbOlsg?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot.After changing the code as you wrote, I still had the issue, but afterwards I watched the code in Plunker that you sent and found out the main problem. The issues was that in routeProvider I was writing the controller name (referencing to function) not in string (it should be string  'controllerName').

Comment: Yes. That's also written I my answer. Mark as answer if it helped to resolve the problem.